# Verify load rows in table Power Center

Tags: load, informatica-powercenter

I'm new in Power Center. I would like to know if there is in Power Center a way to check if all rows read from a source table are loaded on a target table.

Is there for example some variable I can query or a way to do this?

Thanks

Luca

Answer (score 1):

You can check an infa metadata table for the run statistics.
Once all loaded, you can check below tables like status <>'Succeeded' and see if there is any failure. You can also see if anything is rejected or not. This also holds historical data.

- REP_SESS_LOG - Details of workflow, session statistics - like source rows loaded, rows rejected, target rows loaded, rejected etc. session status - like succeeded, failed etc.
- REP_SESS_TBL_LOG - This view contains information about the status of an individual session run against a target. It provides the last update time, row counts, and error status based on a last update timestamp on a per target basis.